# Understanding Google Play Store Search censorship

Tags: google-play

I have an App in the Play Store called 'Sexgame' with a light sexual theme:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cyberdynesoftware.sexgame

Unfortunately, the app cannot be found in the Play Store when searching for 'sexgame'. Even when scrolling down a lot, it simply doesn't show up. This has been tested by various Android users in different countries.

I've contacted the support from Google hoping they would explain to me why, but only received a very vague answer:

> I've investigated this matter and identified an issue that may impact your app's eligibility for promotion on the Play Store.

In an answer to a followup question they bluntly refused to explain this any further:

> As much as I'd like to help, I’m not able to provide any more information or a better answer to your question.

Naturally, I would like to know what exactly it is that led to this situation in order to examine, whether or not I can change something to change this situation. I don't understand, why Google decides to be non-transparent about their censorship rules.

Here are a few things I've considered so far:

The App's name contains the word 'sex'. I've temporarily (for two weeks or so) renamed the App to 'Game of Love', but it did not show up in the search results either when searching for 'game of love'.

Another thing I can think of is that although the App itself does not contain any reference to alcohol, the App's description mentions the possibility to play the game as a drinking game. Could this be the issue?

If I were to change the description removing the option to play the game as a drinking game, how would I trigger a re-evaluation? Maybe the renaming of the App had no effect, because it was never re-evaluated.

I've been very careful with the wording of the texts in the App and avoided words that could be considered offensive or vulgar. But maybe they simply don't like the game itself. That would be something I cannot change. I doubt however, that they really test all Apps in this depth.

I am aware that this is a difficult question for which there might not be a straight answer. It will probably solicit some guessing. I hope however, that the importance of this question out weights this concern.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with writing code, and is probably off-topic for SO.

Comment: I've asked this question before on 'Android Enthusiasts', but it was put on hold, because it is primarily of concern for developers. If it's off-topic here too, where can I ask a question about Google Play Store Search accessing the experience of other Android developers?